# How to intercept browser (android, chromium) back button with ask() in javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, chromium

I tried most of the solutions here (SO) and they don't work.

What I am trying to achieve is when user is on an android device, in browser chromium and accidentally presses the triangle button (back) I want him to confirm his action (and be able to cancel), not to go back immediately. If anyone knows a solution I will be so happy to use it.. thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the `onbeforeunload` event, but note this will fire whenever the page is unloaded (ie, the user clicks another link, or types a new URL in the address bar). There is no workaround for that

Comment: thanks for the clarification @RoryMcCrossan  I was wondering will that ever fire, but now I see how it works....

Comment: well, @GabeSechan , you maybe don't, you write on SO and according to your resume have been a professional developer for more than a decade, but there are people with other jobs, that do not possess such experience.... and in this particular case I need to ease their job, it is not for porn or any other thing like this.... but since it cannot be done I must rethink of the whole conception, thanks for the reply.

Comment: @marto Almost nobody does.  This kind of behavior is considered BAD user design.  Don't do it.